# In angel.co, is the ”reply to this email with 3 available times in the next week“ response message sent by the website automatically or by recruiters?

Tags: recruitment, united-states, websites

In https://angel.co/, I received  messages from two  interested recruiters from different companies, whose job descriptions say that they don't provide working visa sponsorship.
I replied to them  individually  that I prefer positions with working visa sponsorship opportunities and if it is a good idea to them.

Three minutes later, I got messages from each recruiter saying

> **AngelList Talent**
>
> You matched with companyname
>
> recruitername from companyname reached out
> 2 days ago and you responded with interest.  Reply to this email with
> 3 available times in the next week.

I was surprised how fast I received the responses.

Three hours later, one recruiter replied saying they couldn't offer sponsorship. I haven't heard of the other recruiter yet.

Now I was wondering whether the messages ”reply to this email with 3 available times in the next week“ are automatic generated by angel list website or are templates manually selected and sent by the recruiters?

Should I expect a more humanly response from the second recruiter?

Should I reply to the second recruiter with 3 available times in the next week?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: ”reply to this email with 3 available times in the next week“ is a bit unclear, at least to me... is that literally what they replied? What is 3 available times?

Comment: Correct. See my update. @DarkCygnus

Comment: @DarkCygnus I've used Angelist before. "3 available times" to talk on the phone with a recruiter or hiring manager, but agree the language is missing context.

Comment: @Tim The email is completely autogenerated.

Comment: @jcmack Thanks. Should I reply to the second recruiter with 3 available times in the next week?

Comment: @Tim Yes reply back with your availability if you're interested in chatting more!

Comment: If you need a working visa sponsorship, why are you even looking at jobs "whose job descriptions say that they don't provide working visa sponsorship". It seems like a waste of both your time and the employer's time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question about the inner workings of a specific site (even if we can speculate, deduce or assume the answer).

Comment: @Tim You guessed my nationality and got it wrong.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Sorry. I meant the country where you have its PR or citizenship and therefore  don't face the difficulty that I do.

Comment: @Tim - Patricia's point is very valid. If they don't over visa sponsorship and you need it, there is absolutely no point replying.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan  I am not sure who removed my previous comment. I would repeat again. Even though I am not a PR or citizen where you are, I still deserve respect. Nowhere did I mention that I initiated the contact.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I was wondering whether the messages ”reply to this email with 3 available times in the next week“ are automatic generated by angel list website or are templates manually selected and sent by the recruiters?

Given that both messages were delivered in apparently the same time, and with the same phrasing and content we can safely assume it's **automated response from part of Angel List** (it even suggests so in the AngelList Talent part, and the noreply email shown in the image you included).

> Should I expect a more humanly response from the second recruiter?

To be fair, the first one gave you a humanly response, by saying that they do not offer such visas.

It's only logical to expect the other recruiter to reply back at some point, how soon would depend on that recruiter specifically. There is also the chance that they do not reply back at all, and based on some googling and surfing  I did (I'm no AngelList expert, though), seems that many people don't ever get responses from certain recruiters.

I'd also suggest you keep your options open and consider/search other jobs while waiting for them to reply, in case it's not what you though or if they never reply back.